# c++: Can I prohibt references to objects of MyClass?

Tags: c++, oop, reference

### Question

Is anything possible to prevent consumers from creating references and pointers to objects of a certain class type?

```cpp
MyClass object; // default constructor. shall be possible
MyClass& reference = object; // shall be impossible
MyClass* pointer = &object; // shall be impossible
```

So the question is how I can implement `MyClass` so that the above three properties are achieved.

### What I tried

I tried by defining literally every operator private. I then tried making MyClass an actual using of a pair-type of which the second part is a reference in order to make use of the fact that the compiler will prohibit references to refernces. But it does not work because it is a reference to a pair.

### Requirements

So long as the consumer experiences as though MyClass behaves as a class, I am happy for MyClass to actually be anything (e.g., array, pointer, reference already, etc.). But it should not require dynamic memory.

## The why

I let users write a class with a mask template type. These are used later on so that attributes of said class are of different kind once a code-generator has transformed the user-class into a derived class. If now the user makes a reference to an attributes that has been formerly code-generated in the same fashion as the outer class, the mask types are incompatible by design pattern. Hence, I provide a reference type from which all masked types inherit. Consider, e.g. a `Spline<mask>` that inherits from `template<mask> using SplineRef = SplineBase<mask::numbertype>` because splinebase is really the only thing necessary to pass information like when setting a value in the nodal or abscissae arrays, while at the same time extracting those information that is compatible between all evaluaton-kind masks. And then, to prevent the user from not using SplineRef but instead Spline& ref=obj, I would like the latter to cause a compilation error. That seems for me in the present code situation the cleanest continuation.

Comment: `MyClass* pointer = &object;` probably as you could overload `operator&` for the class and perhaps thrown an exception.

Comment: @RichardCritten there is still `std::addressof` to bypass `operator&`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai true

Comment: It would be possible to declare but not define an overload of `operator&()` - which would typically cause a linker error rather than a compile error.    But that doesn't prevent `std::addressof()` working.

Comment: but the matlab-type engineer users won't know that :)

Comment: Note: if the requirements could be satisfied then you could never pass an instance of `MyClass` to a function by pointer or reference to as this would require the initialisation of the parameter.

Comment: @RichardCritten You are right. I imply that between the actual payload class and the consumer is a handle class. Now if at passing the compiler is incentivised to copy the handle instead of passing its address, then the copy constructor of the handle could throw an error. Maybe this yields towards a solution.

Comment: This is fundamentally impossible in C++. C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: rather than setting up a complicated barrier for your users I'd rather document it and expect the user wants to use stuff the right way, because if they don't then no matter what you do to prevent them from doing the wrong thing, they will find a way

Comment: I read your “why” carefully and didn’t follow. As others have said, it’s fundamentally not possible. Either document it or try a different approach.

Comment: If taking the address of, or making a reference to, and instance of your type is a problem, you have most likely designed your thing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is impossible.

For any object `x` of any kind a user can always do

```
auto&& ref = x;
```

to get a reference to the object.

Similarly a user can always do

```
auto ptr = std::addressof(x);
```

to get a pointer to the object. Even if `std::addressof` is somehow disallowed, a user can always achieve the same with a sequence of `reinterpret_cast`s.

This can only be enforced by documentation or a linter or other external tool that understands where a reference is formed to the specific type.

Comment: At least `auto myclass::operator&(this auto&&) = delete;` forces the user not to use the operator, which is a hint on what must not be done.